# Can a case insensitive comparison be made on html side in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, comparison, guid, case-insensitive

I have an application that uses a backend with a lot of guids. Backend is C# based.

On the frontend, i need to sometimes show things based on the status of something.  These status' are represented by various guids.  I want to know if i can do a case insensitive comparison on the angular html side inside of an ng-if or ng-show.

Example is pseudo-code

```
<button ng-show="myGuidWithUnknownCasing.toUpperCase()  === '6C08185C-163E-4FAD-B743-65EA170249CF'" ng-click="setReview(nurseleaderapplication);">Review</button>
```

This method doesn't work and probably shouldn't, since i'm attempting to run the uppercase function inside of an angular thing and who knows whats going on there!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

And as usual, with any other question, the answer presents itself seconds after asking.

Had to add the uppercase word 'before' the variable.

```
<button ng-show="uppercase | myGuidWithUnknownCasing  === '6C08185C-163E-4FAD-B743-65EA170249CF'" ng-click="setReview(nurseleaderapplication);">Review</button>
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in angular 2 or in angular 4?